# JavaBeans throwing NullPointer while the field is NOT null

Tags: java, database, nullpointerexception, javabeans

I've got a problem with my beans model and I just CAN'T figure out why it's throwing a nullpointer at all.

Here is my MessageModel:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "privateMessages")
public class MessageModel {

@Id
@Column(unique = true, updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(unique = false, updatable = false)
private String userFrom;

@Column(unique = false, updatable = false)
private String userTo;

@Column(unique = false, updatable = false)
private String Message;

@Column(unique = false, updatable = true)
private Boolean isRead;

@Column(unique = false, updatable = true)
private Boolean isDeleted;

@Column(unique = false, updatable = true)
private String insertDate;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserFrom() {
    return userFrom;
}

public void setUserFrom(String userFrom) {
    this.userFrom = userFrom;
}

public String getUserTo() {
    return userTo;
}

public void setUserTo(String userTo) {
    this.userTo = userTo;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    Message = message;
}

public Boolean getRead() {
    return isRead;
}

public void setRead(Boolean read) {
    isRead = read;
}

public Boolean getDeleted() {
    return isDeleted;
}

public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
    isDeleted = deleted;
}

public String getDate() {
    return insertDate;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    insertDate = date;
}

}
```

Here is the method I use to set the variables:

```
    public void createUserNote(String msg, String playername, String playerto) {
    MessageModel model = new MessageModel();

    model.setRead(false);
    model.setUserFrom(playername);
    model.setUserTo(playerto);
    model.setDeleted(false);
    model.setMessage(msg);

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d M hh:mm");
    String date = format.format(new Date());
    model.setDate(date);

    plugin.getDatabase().save(model);
}
```

Maybe you can help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "the field is NOT null", what are you referring to?

Comment: Why @SintoKItteera I don't think the error is on that?

Comment: I don't know Java, but you're setting the date to a string not to a Date variable. What happens if you just model.setDate(new Date())?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the `insertDate` member to `date`, or rename `get/setDate` to `get/setInsertDate`.

It appears that some library is using reflection to try and find the getter/setter for the field `insertDate`. As the setter doesn't match the field name (and thus doesn't adhere to the JavaBeans convention) it is failing with a particularly unhelpful error message.

Comment: Getting the same weird error, used getinsertDate (since the variable is insertDate

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your problem is that it is looking for a method called 'getInsertDate()' but you have renamed the method to getDate(), and as such it doesn't know how to call it. Try changing the getter and setter back to the default naming and try again.

The NullPointer is possibly something along the lines of a failure to get the method for execution, as opposed to failure executing the method.

Comment: The message says `get insertDate`, not `getInsertDate`: it seems to be referring to the field.

Comment: I've said exactly the same thing as the one you marked as solution... although I suppose I didn't explicitly tell you to fix the constructor too...